# Get option.remove work in firefox javascript only

Tags: javascript

I have an class remover that works just fine in IE och Chrome, wont get any errors but in firefox. it dosent work at all.
Just get an error thats thas remove is not a function.

I been trying different ways to make it work, but none of them removes the class.

```
function removeDice(){
 document.getElementsByClassName("dice")[0].remove(0);
}
```

An nice function that lets me remove dice classes one by one...
works in chrome but not firefox.

Been reading different methods here in stackoverflow and tried this

```
document.getElementById("dice").className =
   document.getElementById("dice").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/g , '' )
```

But no luck either.
Any tips ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Zb5Pd/)

```
function removeClass(classToRemove){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove);

  if (!elems) return;
  for (var i=elems.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    var elem=elems[i];
    var classes=elem.className.split(" ");
    classes.splice(classes.indexOf(classToRemove),1);
    elem.className=classes.join(" ");
  }
}
```

Comment: @mpungjan hmm, i didn't really work.
If I have only one "dice" class nothing happen. If i have 2, the second one just change value =/

Comment: Okej, after a slightly change on row    
var classes=elem.className.split(" ");  I putted the question marks together. but now it removes all of the classes instead of only on at the time =/

Comment: Problem solved :) I changed I++ to I-- in the array :) thank you

Comment: Sorry, my ipad changes i to I all the time. I reversed the loop for you and added a missing join!

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeAttribute()`

```
document.getElementById("dice")[0].removeAttribute("class");
```

### UPDATED:

Do this way:-

```
function removeClassFromAllElements(){
    var objClass = document.getElementsByClassName("YOUR-CLASS-NAME");
    var tempLen = objClass.length;
    for (i=0; i<tempLen; i++) {
        objClass[0].removeAttribute("class");
    }
}

removeClassFromAllElements();
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/VCMHW/)**

Comment: That would remove all classes from the object.

Comment: @Siva . Since dice is the className, i cant get the element by Id.

Comment: That acctually work, but it removes all the classes at once, I need to remove only on at the time. look at the other answer, i changed the for loop to i-- instead of i++ and it worked like a charm.

Thanks